# Show progress dialog in adapter

Tags: android, adapter, progressdialog

I want to show progress dialog in adapter such as BaseExpandableListAdapter and BaseAdapter where I get some data some from Google api and it takes times so it's better to show response to the user. I don't know it's not showing but I have added the same code in activity and it's working.

```
pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MapActivity.this, "dialog title",
                    "dialog message", false);
pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pgress);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // do the thing that takes a long time

        MapWalking = getDistanceInfo(p, dest);
        MapDriving = getDistanceInfo2(p, dest);
        MapTransit = getDistanceInfo3(p, dest);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

```html
 public class ExpandListAdapter2 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

  Context context;
  LayoutInflater inflater;

  private List<Bank> banks=null;

  private List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist2 = null;
  private ArrayList<AnywallPost> arraylist;


  String MapWalking;
  String MapDriving;
  String MapTransit;


  public ExpandListAdapter2(Context context,
          List<AnywallPost> AnywallPostlist2) {
   this.context = context;
   this.AnywallPostlist2 = AnywallPostlist2;
   inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   this.arraylist = new ArrayList<AnywallPost>();
   this.arraylist.addAll(AnywallPostlist2);




   for (AnywallPost bank2 : AnywallPostlist2) {
    bank2.setChildren(new ArrayList<AnywallPost>());



    bank2.getChildren().add(bank2);
    //Log.d("array",branch.get("NameVal").toString());


   }

  }


  public class ViewHolder {
   TextView TVal;
   SegmentedGroup segmented;
   Button book;
   TextView lt111;
   TextView lt222;
   TextView lt333;

   TextView Name;
   ImageView falg;

   public ViewHolder(View v) {
    this.TVal = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
    this.segmented = (SegmentedGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.segmentedmode);
    this.lt111 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewlt1);
    this.lt222 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewlt2);
    this.lt333 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewlt3);
    this.Name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewserviceName);
    this.falg=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewserviceImg);
    this.book=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);



   }


  }

  public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

   return AnywallPostlist2.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
  }

  public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
   for(int i=0;i<AnywallPostlist2.size();i++){
    if(i==groupPosition){
     System.out.println("Nothing");
 
    }
    else{
     lv.collapseGroup(i);
    }
    
   }
   super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
  }
  @Override
  public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
   return childPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
   final AnywallPost parent2 = AnywallPostlist2.get(groupPosition);
   final AnywallPost child = parent2.getChildren().get(childPosition);

   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_itemfinal3, parentView, false);


   /*final TextView TVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
   SegmentedGroup segmented=(SegmentedGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.segmentedmode);
   lt11 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlt1);
   lt22=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlt2);
   lt33=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlt3);
   Button book=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);*/
   sid = parent2.get("Sid").toString();
   holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
   holder.lt111.setOnClickListener(this);
   holder.lt222.setOnClickListener(this);
   holder.lt333.setOnClickListener(this);

   pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MapActivity.this, "dialog title",
     "dialog message", false);
   pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pgress);
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     // do the thing that takes a long time
// do the thing that takes a long time


     MapWalking = getDistanceInfo(p, dest);
     MapDriving = getDistanceInfo2(p, dest);
     MapTransit = getDistanceInfo3(p, dest);

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
       pDialog.dismiss();
      }
     });
    }
   }).start();
   

}
}

public String getDistanceInfo(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

   // Destination of route
   String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

   String dura = "";
   try {

    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String output = "json";
    String mode = "mode=walking";
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode;
    String key="key=AIzaSyAQokRsF58j9EeK9VsOgFFgU3IGEpoCSfM";

    // Output format


    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters +"&"+ key;


    //String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + str_origin + "," + str_dest + "&destination=" + destinationAddress + "&mode=driving&sensor=false";

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


    response = client.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
    int b;
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
     stringBuilder.append((char) b);
    }
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }

   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   try {

    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");

    JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONObject duration = steps.getJSONObject("duration");
    dura = duration.getString("text");

   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return dura;
  }
```

Comment: please post your code in BaseExpandableListAdapter or BaseAdapter and the code you get data from Google API

Comment: @PhanVănLinh I have posted BaseExpandableListAdapter and the function to get duration from google direction api. but note that the adapter inside my main activity class , same java class file.

Answer (score 0):

In your BaseAdapter make a reference to context:

```
private Context mContext = null;
```

And add a constructor

```
public MyListAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

Then reference context when initializing your progress dialog

```
pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "dialog title",
                "dialog message", false);
```